# Why doesn't my script open my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this snippet of code for my personal website that uses JavaScript to activate the Hamburger menu. However, it does not work and I am not sure why.  The other JS in my code works no problem.

Here is the Code:

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById(".navbarNav");

function hideShow() {
  if (navbar.style.display == "block") {
    navbar.style.display = "hideShow()";
  } else {
    navbar.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Edward Wynman</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/Files/EddieReume.pdf">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Let me know if you need anything else like the CSS or other code.

Comment: hideShow() is not an acceptable value for style.display.  "none" will hide the element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: make it to `display: none;` , also ID isn't correct you need to delete the dot because it isn't a class

Comment: Looking at your code, this line `document.getElementById(".navbarNav");` seems incorrect as you are looking for elements by ID but the string contains a dot `.` in the name (there are no elements with that ID) - also, your tags are not correctly matched either (make sure you open / close all your tags correctly)

Comment: So how would I go about changing the JS to work, Im not the best with JS

Comment: @PyMan like this: `var navbar = document.getElementById("navbarNav");

function hideShow() {
  if (navbar.style.display == "block") {
    navbar.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    navbar.style.display = "block";
  }
}` paste this code and your IDE (vscode, etc...) will prettify correctly this by adding spaces and tabs

Comment: When i go to test it with live server it wont work when I click on the hamburger menu button. Does it have to be within a certain area of the code?

Comment: here the jffidle of the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/laaouatni/6zdo905p/

Comment: You shouldn't' t be manually manipulating a Bootstrap collapse element _anyway_. Bootstrap provides everything you're likely to need already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your markup, are you trying to use Bootstrap? In your code I can see data attributes such as `data-bs-toggle` which indicate you are. If so, make sure you are using the [JavaScript and CSS files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/) needed to make this work.

With that added, it works with your code - no custom JS needed (screenshots below)

[image: Standard menu]
[image: Menu opened]

Your code working can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmonk/423c6xnf/2/)

If you want to know how to create a custom bit of JS to trigger this, please comment and I'll update my answer accordingly.